# VBA: Workbook.Close loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following portion of the code for a given active worksheet:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim myMessage
    If ActiveSheet.Range("I5").Value > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Some cells are empty" _
        & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Please, fill in the empty cells to proceed", _
        vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "ERROR!"
        Cancel = True
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Unprotect ("123")
        Worksheets("Instructions").Visible = True
        Worksheets("Instructions").Activate
        For Each sh In Worksheets
            If sh.Name <> "Instructions" Then
                sh.Visible = xlVeryHidden
            End If
        Next sh
        ThisWorkbook.Protect ("123")
        myMessage = MsgBox("Do you want to save and close this file?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Workbook 1")
            If myMessage = vbYes Then
                Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True                    
                ThisWorkbook.Close True
            ElseIf myMessage = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            Else
                'nothing
            End If

    End If
End Sub
```

In general, upon pressing the close button on the workbook itself, the idea is to check a given cell of a given active worksheet for a non-zero value. If it is non-zero, the user has to fill in certain empty cells first and the workbook is not closed. Alternatively, the "Instruction" worksheet is activated and the user receives a message box of what to do next (by doing this, instead of simply no msgbox and sticking with the usual system "SAVE/NO" prompt, is that I want to eliminate the possibility of a user pressing the "No" button, which will lead to no save being made). The only problem I have is the one-time loop I get when a user selects "Yes" answer: the same message box re-appears (apparently, because the procedure goes through the code line again!). 
I would appreciate if you could suggest me the way I could avoid this loop.

Comment: Why do you need to replicate the feature already implemented in Excel: that pop-up dialog prompt on Workbook close  "Do you want to save the changes..." with 3 standard option Buttons? Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell , thanks for your comment. As I mentioned in my question section, I want to avoid the possibility of a user accidentally pressing the "No" button, which will lead to no save being made. It is the only reason I implemented my own message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not going to allow the user not to save then why not force a save.  You can replace the entire message box prompt section:

```
myMessage = MsgBox("Do you want to save and close this file?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Workbook 1")
        If myMessage = vbYes Then
            Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True                    
            ThisWorkbook.Close True
        ElseIf myMessage = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        Else
            'nothing
        End If
```

with

```
ThisWorkbook.Save
```

This will force the save and close the workbook.

Comment: Oh, dear! It was so easy! In fact, I have used ThisWorkbook.Save line before in this code but then typed ThisWorkbook.Close (I looked at the .Save feature as if it would ONLY save my workbook. But I did not take into account the fact that the Excel was already implementing the closure of the workbook! Now, I realised my error.

Thanks a ton, @daytonrazorback!